# sprockets/sinatra

Tags: ruby, encoding, sinatra, sprockets

I'm using sprockets with sinatra.

```
require 'sprockets'

set :assets, Sprockets::Environment.new

# Configure sprockets
settings.assets.append_path "assets/js"
settings.assets.append_path "assets/js/libs"
settings.assets.append_path "assets/css"

get "/js/:file.js" do
  content_type "application/javascript"
  settings.assets["#{params[:file]}.js"]
end

get "/js/libs/:file.js" do
  content_type "application/javascript"
  settings.assets["libs/#{params[:file]}.js"]
end

get "/css/:file.css" do
  content_type "text/css"
  settings.assets["#{params[:file]}.css"]
end
```

I get this error only with this javascript file. Not sure what I can do about it, I have encoding: utf-8 in my app.rb.

```
174.31.173.110 - - [16/Dec/2012 17:08:53] "GET /js/libs/modernizr-2.0.6.js HTTP/1.0" 200 - 0.0017
E, [2012-12-16T17:08:53.568260 #12145] ERROR -- : app error: /var/www/myapp/releases/20121217010420/assets/js/libs/modernizr-2
.0.6.js has a invalid US-ASCII byte sequence (Sprockets::EncodingError)
```

Comment: If you check the encoding of the mderinizr-2.js file, what is it?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I figured it out, I added:

```
  Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8
  Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8
```

to config.ru